# why can't I access imagedata in main?

Tags: c++, c, vtk

I am trying to write a programme to read MRI data by using VTK and C++. But I can't get spacing of MRI raw data in main.
The "GetSpacing" only works in "ReadImageData" function. I think I made some mistake in C++ programming. But I don't know where it is.

```
vtkImageData* ReadImageData(string mri_imagedata_file)
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkMetaImageReader> reader =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkMetaImageReader>::New();
    reader->SetFileName(mri_imagedata_file.c_str());
    reader->Update();
    vtkImageData* metaimage = reader->GetOutput();
    double sp[3];
    metaimage->GetSpacing(sp);
    cout << sp[0] << " " << sp[1] << " " << sp[2] <<endl; //<----------It works here.
    return metaimage;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " MRI image data" <<endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    string mri_imagedata_file = argv[1];// Input "prost00.mhd"

    vtkImageData* metaimage = ReadImageData(mri_imagedata_file);
    double sp2[3];
    metaimage->GetSpacing(sp2);
    cout << sp2[0] << " " << sp2[1] << " " << sp2[2] << endl; //<-----It doesn't work here

}
```

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: What is `spacing` and why don't you pass it to `GetSpacing`? The [documentation](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageData.html#aab194f5cebd12e406fbd9e3c7047ed0f) shows you should either pass in an array or use the return value `double*`.

Comment: @PeterWood  Thank you for reminding me. The code is modified :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `vtkSmartPointer<vtkMetaImageReader>` is a kind of smart pointer whatever,  `reader`  points to in the function is destructed when `ReadImageData` returns. That includes what `metaimage` is pointing to.

```
    return metaimage;
    // reader->~();  // Destructed here. Including what is pointed to by metaimage. 
}
```

A good solution would be to return the smart pointer instead of `metaimage`. That way what is pointed to by `reader` will not be destructed when `ReadImageData` returns and will be available in main.

Comment: Thank you. That's the solution. I return vtkSmartPointer<vtkMetaImageReader> reader In the function. It works!!!

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that `vtkMetaImageReader::GetOutput()` returns pointer to some `vtkMetaImageReader` internal data, so when you exit `ReadImageData` your `reader` is destroyed and the pointer you return becomes invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to pass the array as a parameter to `GetSpacing` in `main`, so it calls the overload that returns a `double*`, leaving your array untouched.

You're also printing an array called `spacing` although it looks like you want the spacing in `sp2`.

Comment: Thank you. But it's a copy/paste mistake when I post the question.

Comment: @Yao If the current code in the question is the one you're actually using, then your problem is the one described in my second paragraph.